# Stop the current video playing when user play another video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have a sidebar which contains multiple videos, now user can play and pause any video he wants, but when a certain video is playing and the user plays another video both videos is playing,

Now I want when one video is playing and the user plays another video it should stop the current playing video.

Here is a live demo: [Live demo](https://videomill-bot.audiencevideo.com/editor/)

Here is a function to play pause the videos

```
 $(".playpause").on('click', function(){

                    var videotag = $(this).parent().find("video")[0];
                    if(videotag.paused==true) {
                            $(this).parent().find("video")[0].play();
                            $(this).css("opacity", 0)
                            $(videotag).on('ended',function(){
                                    $('.playpause').css("opacity", 1);
                            });


                    } else if(videotag.paused==false) {
                            $(this).parent().find("video")[0].pause();
                            $(this).css("opacity", 1)
                            $('.playpause').show();
                    }

            });
```

What do I need to change to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a video starts playing you can select all other videos and call the `pause()` method on them. Also note that you can tidy your logic by caching selectors and defining the `ended` event once. The `else if` is also redundant as `paused` only has two states. Try this:

```js
var $allVideos = $('video').on('ended', function() {
  $('.playpause').css('opacity', 1);
});
var $allPlayPause = $('.playpause');

$allPlayPause.on('click', function() {
  var $playpause = $(this),
    video = $playpause.parent().find('video')[0];
  
  if (video.paused) {
    video.play();
    $allPlayPause.css('opacity', 1);
    $playpause.css('opacity', 0)

    // pause all but this:
    $allVideos.not(video).each(function(i, vid) {
      vid.pause();
    });
  } else {
    video.pause();
    $playpause.css('opacity', 1)
    $('.playpause').show();
  }
});
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: el is not defined?

Comment: My bad, I changed the argument name whilst writing the code. Answer updated to fix the error

Comment: Good , now when I play another video it stops the current playing video but the playpause button its hidden, what do I need to change so that when video stop also the playpause button should be visible?

Comment: Updated again for you. I would suggest you use a CSS class to set `opacity: 0` instead of inline styling, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can pause **all** videos and then start the one which was clicked:

```
$(".playpause").on('click', function() {

  // PAUSE EVERY SINGLE VIDEO IN .sidebar
  $('.sidebar video').each( function(index, element) {
    $(element).parent().find("video")[0].pause();
  });

  // PLAY THE VIDEO WHICH WAS CLICKED
  $(this).parent().find("video")[0].play();

});
```